# How to find the previous occurence of a value 'a' before some value 'b'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I join two data frames and have the resulting data frame as below.Now I want to

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|a        |b          |       c   |          d        |       e |          f |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|        7|          2|          1|2015-04-12 23:59:01|     null|              null |
|       15|          2|          2|2015-04-12 23:59:02|         |                   |
|       11|          2|          4|2015-04-12 23:59:03|     null|               null|
|        3|          2|          4|2015-04-12 23:59:04|     null|               null|
|        8|          2|          3|2015-04-12 23:59:05| {NORMAL} 2015-04-12 23:59:05|
|       16|          2|          3|2017-03-12 23:59:06|     null|               null|
|        5|          2|          3|2015-04-12 23:59:07|     null|               null|
|       18|          2|          3|2015-03-12 23:59:08|     null|               null|
|       17|          2|          1|2015-03-12 23:59:09|     null|               null|
|        6|          2|          1|2015-04-12 23:59:10|     null|               null|
|       19|          2|          3|2015-03-12 23:59:11|     null|               null|
|        9|          2|          3|2015-04-12 23:59:12|     null|               null|
|        1|          2|          2|2015-04-12 23:59:13|     null|               null|
|        1|          2|          2|2015-04-12 23:59:14|     null|               null|
|        1|          2|          2|2015-04-12 23:59:15|     null|               null|
|       10|          3|          2|2015-04-12 23:59:16|     null|               null|
|        4|          2|          3|2015-04-12 23:59:17| {NORMAL}|2015-04-12 23:59:17|
|       12|          3|          1|2015-04-12 23:59:18|     null|               null|
|       13|          3|          1|2015-04-12 23:59:19|     null|               null|
|       14|          2|          1|2015-04-12 23:59:20|     null|               null|
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Now I have to find the first occuring 1 before each 3 in column c .For example

```
|        4|          2|          3|2015-04-12 23:59:17| {NORMAL}|2015-04-12 23:59:17|
```

Before this record I want to know the first occured 1 in column c which is

```
|       17|          2|          1|2015-03-12 23:59:09|     null|               null|
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you explain `Before this record I want to know the first occured 1 in column c` then you should get help quickly. And can you update how you are joining the two dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark window function lag `import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

In first step you filter your data on the column "c" based on value as either 1 or 3. You will get data similar to

```
dft.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  7|  2|  1|
|  2| 15|  2|  3|
|  3| 11|  2|  3|
|  4|  3|  2|  1|
|  5|  8|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Next, define the window

```
val w = Window.orderBy("id")
```

Once this is done, create a new column and put previous value in it

```
dft.withColumn("prev", lag("c",1).over(w)).show()
+---+---+---+---+----+
| id|  a|  b|  c|prev|
+---+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  7|  2|  1|null|
|  2| 15|  2|  3|   1|
|  3| 11|  2|  3|   3|
|  4|  3|  2|  1|   3|
|  5|  8|  2|  3|   1|
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Finally filter on the values of column "c" and "prev"

Note: Do combine the steps when you are writing final code, so as to apply filter directly.

Comment: I do not think it is a lag here.Because lag just lags the column where here  I need to iterate through the sequence and check for the first 1 before first 3 in the column c

Comment: But once you have flittered the rows, the values will be wither 1 or 3 i.e. sequence of 131333131331. So now I if I'm interested in the first value before 3, then from above solution I can get it. Second scenario can be getting 1 before all values of 3 for e.g. in sequence 1331 output should be (3,1),(3,1) - for only first occurrence of 1. Which one is it?

Comment: It  is not for all values of 3 But only first value before first 3 in a sequence of continuous 3

Comment: can you post the output from the example dataset I've used